# Adding strings to an Array in Abstract class A, from an extended class B in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, abstract

I'm writing a small program to demonstrate the factory design pattern. It's a food court application which serves different types of food like Chinese, Italian, Sushi etc. I've created an array in the abstract class below, and I'm trying to populate it by adding a string via an extended class.

```
abstract public class FoodCourt
{
    String name;            //e.g. italian, chinese etc...
    static String [] dailySpecial = new String[10];
    int idx = new Random().nextInt(dailySpecial.length);
    String random = (dailySpecial[idx]);

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void takeOrder()
    {       
        System.out.println("You ordered " + random + " from our list of Daily Specials");
    }

    public void serve()
    {
        System.out.println(" -> Serving " + random + " from our " + name + " menu"); //Serving Chow Mein from our Chinese menu
    }

    public void printList()
    {
        for (String name : dailySpecial) 
        {
            System.out.println(name);
        }   
    }
}
```

Extended class

```
public class Chinese extends FoodCourt
{
    public Chinese()
    {
        name = "Chinese";
        String s = "Chicken Chow Mein";
        dailySpecial[0] = s;
    }
}
```

Each extended class (there are 4) will add a special dish to the array but it is being output to the screen as follows:

```
You ordered null from our list of Daily Specials
-> Serving null from our Chinese menu
Chinese food served
```

When it should be something like

```
You ordered Chicken Chow Mein from our list of Daily Specials
-> Serving Chicken Chow Mein from our Chinese menu
Chinese food served
```

If anyone could help out and see why nothing is being added in that would be great. (If necessary I can post the rest of the classes).

Comment: Well you're only filling `dailySpecial[0]` but you're picking a random element from the whole array, so chances are it'll be null. I agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels, though, in that you should probably rethink your design.

Answer (score 1):

Your OOP structure is way off and you look to be misusing inheritance as this is not how inheritance works or should work. Your Chinese class should not extend FoodCourt since it does not satisfy the "is-a" rule or the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). I recommend a re-design with a view towards composition:

- FoodCourt should hold a List of objects that extend Restaurant, say called restaurantList. Do it right from the beginning.
- You could give Restaurant a `getDailySpecial()` method that each subclass extends
- FoodCourt will call this method when iterating through the list.
- You would make Restaurant abstract and your factory would create concrete Restaurant instances.
- The parent class shouldn't have a fixed array as you're implementing things.
- To get a random daily special, simply get a random Restaurant from the list and call its get daily special method: `restaurantList.get(random.nextInt(restaurantList.size())).getDailySpecial();`

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response. I'm going to take your advice and try implementing a better overall approach.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are those lines:

```
static String [] dailySpecial = new String[10];
int idx = new Random().nextInt(dailySpecial.length);
String random = (dailySpecial[idx]);
```

The dailySpecial.length is 10. And in your description, you said that you have 4 extended classes, you are using just 4 position of this array. But you are generating a random integer from 0 to 9.

So,  your string random can be null if the idx is greater than 3.